# R not reading a csv file correctly

Tags: r, csv, import

I have a problem when reading a csv file from R. When I import a dataset from a csv file, columns that are numeric (or at least should be) are getting imported as character and added `\r` at the end. For example a binary sex variable is being read as "1\r" for men and "2\r" for women. At first I thought reading it from Github was the problem but even when reading it from a local file, nothing changed.

I already tried the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` option and the NA 's are not the problem because that column has no NA values. I also tried setting the column type as `number`from Excel. Nothing has worked. Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(cowplot)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr) 
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr) 
library(moments) 
library(readr)
library(rgdal)
library(broom)
library(scales)
library(lemon)
library(ggplot2)
library(survey)
knit_print.data.frame <- lemon_print

#Lectura de Datos y Diccionario
options(stringsAsFactors=F)


df <-  read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pablolopez2733/Aplicada1/master/Bases%20de%20Datos/conjunto_de_datos_envipe2019_csv/conjunto_de_datos_TPer_Vic2_ENVIPE_2019/conjunto_de_datos/conjunto_de_datos_TPer_Vic2_ENVIPE_2019.csv")

df$SEXO
```

which yields:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVvro.png)

Link to the csv: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pablolopez2733/Aplicada1/master/Bases%20de%20Datos/conjunto_de_datos_envipe2019_csv/conjunto_de_datos_TPer_Vic2_ENVIPE_2019/conjunto_de_datos/conjunto_de_datos_TPer_Vic2_ENVIPE_2019.csv

Comment: I believe the problem is with the file. It is easier to read the file get rid of the "\r" and then convert the target columns to numeric. Do you know, beforehand, which columns you would like to convert to numeric?

Comment: Huh, the file is 82MB!. Nevertheless, I just downloaded it and noticed that it does not have a single line break (*wc -l* yields 0) and that indeed many fields have carriage returns (\r) appended before the separating comma. This file does not seem to be properly formatted.

Comment: @HarroCyranka yes I know which columns need to be a number. Hadn´t thought about your suggestion. Let me try. Any help with a script suggestion would be well received.

Comment: Will post an answer, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on OP's comment, this code should work:

```
library(tidyverse)


##Read the file and get rid of carriage trails in all variables


df <-  read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pablolopez2733/Aplicada1/master/Bases%20de%20Datos/conjunto_de_datos_envipe2019_csv/conjunto_de_datos_TPer_Vic2_ENVIPE_2019/conjunto_de_datos/conjunto_de_datos_TPer_Vic2_ENVIPE_2019.csv") %>%
    mutate_all(.funs = ~str_replace_all(.,"[\r]",""))

##Mutate a single variable    
df_mutate_single <-  df %>% 
    mutate(SEXO = parse_number(SEXO)) 

#Use mutate at to pass a vector of variables to convert to numeric

df_mutate_at <- df %>%
    mutate_at(c("AP6_1_2","AP6_1_2", "EDAD"), .funs = ~parse_number(.))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and it still isn't working, try adding

```
strip.white = TRUE
```

as a parameter as well